# Pass data to React (Native) hooks like class-based components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm just starting transitioning to Hooks in React Native, and I have a hard time passing data to child elements. With class-based components, we could do a very simple XML-style passing of props.

### Example with classes

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Child data={"Hello"}/>
        )
    }
}
```

And the child:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Text>{this.props.data}</Text>
        )
    }
}
```

### Example with Hooks:

When using a hook, I was able to pass data via:

```
<Child {...["Hello"]} />
```

The hook would look like:

```
export const Child = (data) => {
    return (
        <Text>{data[0]}</Text>
    )
}
```

Is there a way to refactor just the child classes into hooks and leave calls to these elements untouched (`<Child data={"Hello"}/>` ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if you leave as `<Child data={"Hello"}/>` in your parent component and refactoring `Child` component with hooks, you can access the data just like the following:

```
export const Child = ({data}) => {
   return (
      <Text>{data}</Text>
   )
}
```

Technically `props` has been passed to your component as `const Child = (props) => {}`. Once you destructure `props`, you could have the `data` property as above.

It's called object destructuring, read further [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing a small step:

```
export const Child = (data) => {...
```

should be:

```
export const Child = (props) => {... 
  const {data} = props
```

or:

```
export const Child = ({data}) => {..
```